# R calling user path to clang+llvm

Tags: r, package, llvm-clang

how do we reset the paths that R uses to call clang:

When trying to compile R package from source I get the the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: /Users/user_name/opt/clang+llvm-4.0.1-x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0/bin/clang
configure: CXX: /Users/user_name/opt/clang+llvm-4.0.1-x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0/bin/clang++
checking for gdal-config... /opt/local/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 2.2.4
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... yes
checking for gcc... /Users/user_name/opt/clang+llvm-4.0.1-x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/gk/2c8jpk7d63z66990tsly0wzr0000gn/T/RtmpCtBrqR/R.INSTALLb2c5342f3e/sf':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sf’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
```

In the 3rd line above it reads:

```
configure: CC: /Users/user_name/opt/clang+llvm-4.0.1-x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0/bin/clang


It has a genertic name for account, how do we change this a real account name:

/Users/realaccountname/opt/clang+llvm-4.0.1-x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0/bin/clang
```

P

Comment: The Apple clang does not play well with R. See: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/